# First time setting expiration to already passed time returns True

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

In following test, I am trying to set expiration of the key to already passed time (10 seconds ago). I need it to be able to throw exception if set expiration "failed". I understand, that I can verify expiration time before set the cache, but in some cases may be I'll prefer to avoid separate check.

From (consistent) behaviour I can observe, first time it always "succeed" (return true), when second time its behave as expected (returns false).

```
    [Test]
    public void SetExpirationToPassed()
    {
        var key = "testKey";
        using (var conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            // Given
            var cache = conn.GetDatabase();

            cache.HashSet(key, "full", "test", When.NotExists, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);

            Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);

            // When
            var expiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-10);

            var firstResult = cache.KeyExpire(key, expiresOn, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            var secondResult = cache.KeyExpire(key, expiresOn, CommandFlags.PreferMaster);
            var exists = cache.KeyExists(key);
            var ttl = cache.KeyTimeToLive(key);

            // Then
            secondResult.ShouldBe(false);
            firstResult.ShouldBe(false);
            exists.ShouldBe(false);
            ttl.ShouldBe(null);
        }
    }


    private ConnectionMultiplexer CreateConnection()
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer connection =ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(...);
    }
```

May be I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyExpire` returns a boolean that indicates **whether it was possible to set the expiry**. When you set the expiry into the past, the key *ceases to exist*, so when you try to set it the second time: it fails.

Thus, the expected behaviour should be:

```
firstResult.ShouldBe(true);
secondResult.ShouldBe(false);
exists.ShouldBe(false);
ttl.ShouldBe(null);
```

For consistent runs, you might also want to delete the key before each run:

```
var cache = conn.GetDatabase();
cache.KeyDelete(key);
cache.HashSet(key, "full", "test", When.NotExists);
```

at the top.

With that: it seems to work as expected to me. If you are seeing something different, please say *exactly which result* is unexpected.

Comment: With behaviour you described, it seems to work as expected. I just was expected that set expiration on already expired time will not succeed. I'll need to add this check in the code.